# Aggregate results from CUDA threads

Tags: cuda, synchronization

I am solving minimal dominant set problem on CUDA. Every thread finds some local candiate result and I need to find the best. I am using `__device__` variables for the global result (`dev_bestConfig` and `dev_bestValue`).

I need to do something like this:

```cpp
__device__ configType dev_bestConfig = 0;
__device__ int dev_bestValue = INT_MAX;

__device__ void findMinimalDominantSet(int count, const int *matrix, Lock &lock)
{
    // here is some algorithm that finds local bestValue and bestConfig

    // set device variables
    if (bestValue < dev_bestValue)
    {
        dev_bestValue = bestValue;
        dev_bestConfig = bestConfig;
    }
}
```

I know that this does not work because more threads accesses the memory at the same time so I use this critical section:

```cpp
    // set device variables
    bool isSet = false;
    do
    {
        if (isSet = atomicCAS(lock.mutex, 0, 1) == 0)
        {
            // critical section goes here
            if (bestValue < dev_bestValue)
            {
                dev_bestValue = bestValue;
                dev_bestConfig = bestConfig;
            }
        }
        if (isSet)
        {
            *lock.mutex = 0;
        }
    } while (!isSet);
```

This actually works as expected but it is **really slow**. For example without this critical section it takes 0.1 secodns and with this critical section it takes 1.8 seconds.

What can i do differetly to make it faster?

Comment: Use a standard parallel reduction.  The parallel reduction will find the minimum `bestValue` as well as the ID of the thread that produced it.  At the completion of the reduction, you can simply grab the `bestConfig` using this ID.  Or you can just perform a parallel reduction directly on `bestValue` and `bestConfig`.  Basic parallel reduction tutorial is [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf).

Comment: Could you provide more detail about your problem? Could you provide a runnable code to demonstrate that it is not fast enough. Are your trying to find the minimum of an array? Parallel reduction can do that.

Comment: When I save local results to an array and then search the best value is faster and I dont need any critical sections - so it solves my problem. I originally wanted to prevent to using shared array.

Comment: @MartinVolek: Would you care to add a short answer describing your solution. That was the question will fall off the unanswered question list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually avoided any critical sections and locking at the end. I saved local results to an array and then searched for the best one. The searching can be done sequentially or by parallel reduction.